# jQuery UI + Typescript: jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-ui

Trying to wrangle jQuery UI into a Typescript 2.6.2 project that already has jQuery working nicely, but running into a brick wall. Compiles fine but at runtime I get this:

> Exception has occurred: ReferenceError
>
> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Here is my main.ts file:

```
import $ = require('jquery');
import "jqueryui";

$(document).ready(() =>
{
    $( "#slider" ).slider( {
        orientation: "vertical",
        min: 0,
        max: 150,
        value: 50
    } );
});
```

Here is the index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slider"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

For reference, here are my tsconfig.json, package.json, and the command line I use to transpile to JavaScript:

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions":
    {
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution":"node"
    },
    "include":
    [
        "spec/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tsbugger",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "debug config test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jasmine"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ".git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.2",
    "browserify": "^15.2.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.9.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jqueryui": "^1.11.1",
    "tsify": "^3.0.4",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  }
}
```

build command:

`browserify main.ts --debug -p tsify  1>bundle.js`

How can I get jQuery UI working in Typescript with proper typings?

Comment: [similar question](/q/40858756)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like jquery-ui supports only `amd` modules and global installation. So, try to change tsconfig.json to use `module: 'amd'`, or just add jquery and jqueryui via `<script>` tag without `import` statement.

There code from [jquery-ui.js](https://github.com/sethmcl/jquery-ui/blob/master/jquery-ui.js)

```
(function( factory ) {
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {

    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define([ "jquery" ], factory );
} else {

    // Browser globals
    factory( jQuery );
}
```